# Does datatable work with Ubuntu?

Tags: jquery, linux, datatable, ubuntu-9.04

I've been trying to make a datatable..but the data still does not show although the datatable's head and icons all show.

I tried to get rid of the scripts, one by one, to search for the problem.

I've copied all script at datatable.net (with copy-and-paste) but the data still does not show.

Is this script not compatible with Linux Ubuntu 9, because on other (Windows XP) PC, this data can show.
[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/2013/screenshot2cq.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/2013/screenshot2cq.png)

Comment: What datatable? What programming language are you using? What Frameworks/SDKs/APIs are you using? Is this a desktop application or web application?

Comment: +1 for "What's a datatable?".  Note also that "datatable.net" is not a website, but .NET is not Linux tech. It seems that English is not @Klox first language but that doesn'tmean that we can't help. @klox, can you please try explain a little more what you are trying to do? Thanks

Comment: "head and icons all show" might be a clue ... (Without the icons I might have thought datagrid) ... any ideas?

Comment: @all:i've been change my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code at [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/testing/) should work on Ubuntu browsers.

You can check for yourself. When you visit http://datatables.net/testing/ the unit-tests are automatically run against your browser (which only takes a few seconds.)